# On $H_p$ problem in finite $p$-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group, and let $H_p(G)=\langle x\in G| |x|\neq p\rangle$. Clearly, $H_p(G)$ forms a subgroup of $G$. It is very well-known conjecture called "$H_p$-problem or Hughes conjecture" is settled for various classes of finite $p$-groups. What are the necessary conditions on $G$ such that $H_p(G)$ forms a cyclic subgroup of $G?$

Comment: What does $|x|$ denote in this context?

Comment: @JohannesHahn, the order of a group element.  By the way, I missed the ‘generator brackets’ and so couldn't see why this was ‘clearly’ a group at all; of course it is a group because we are taking the group generated by a set.

Comment: You seem to have left out the actual Hughes conjecture, which is (according to the first page of [Gallian - On the Hughes conjecture](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869375901921), say) that, if $\mathrm H_p(G)$ is a proper, non-trivial subgroup of $G$, then its index is $p$.  Is that what you want, or only the weaker cyclicity condition that you have stated?

Comment: @LSpice the paper you quote mentions a counterexample of exponent 25.

Comment: @YCor, indeed, so, if that is what @ MandeepSingh wants, then I guess that one of the necessary conditions would have to rule out that counterexample.  (Maybe $\mathrm H_p(G)$ is cyclic in that case, prompting this new question?  I do not know.)

Comment: @YCor, I was interested in the properties of $H_p(G)$.